# BCryptPasswordEncoder not matching hashes when password has arabic characters

Tags: java, spring, password-encryption

I have pretty standard DaoAuthenticationProvider

```
        @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        final DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
    }
```

Which works just fine for most passwords but fails if it has arabic characters in it. When a password is created, it is using the same encoder to create the hash and I double-checked that same characters are going into the encoder before writing to the DAO store as are being POSTed with the /login. The passwords include numbers and "special" characters (Latin) as well as UTF-8 Arabic.  Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Based on experience testing out random strings with characters from different languages, java is missing most of the characters in other languages. I'm not sure if this is the only error, but it seems to be one of them, as your password  won't match the strings that java screws up when they take in characters that aren't in it's default characters.

Comment: I was expecting something like this. When the password is created, I can see the correct UTF-8 going into the BCrypt encoder. When someone logs in, I can see the correct UTF-8 in the POST to /login. However, I dont what happens beyond that point and where in Spring the character set would get screwed. It is older Spring 4 implementation.

Comment: Basically, java cannot process the characters itself, which would then screw over spring, which then screws your password application.

Comment: Meh, I do a lot of processing of UTF-8 in java including within this application (a lot of arabic in databases it accesses).  You do have to watch that characterset is specified as UTF-8. It is only the password though that I have had problems.